# posession for non living things

Tags: grammar, possessives

Are all the phrases below correct and if they are , what are the differences?
Car's window / car window / the window of  car

Comment: Normally one would say *car window* (or *window* if the context were obvious).  I'm voting to close because we need context and a sample sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Car's window" generally means the window of a particular car.

"Car window" is a type of window; that which would be part of a car.

"The window of car" without an article is awkward. Better would be "the window of **a** car" or "the window of **the** car."

Answer (score 0):

Non-living objects can definitely possess other things.  Suppose I told you that someone broke my window -- you might ask which window was broken.  I might then tell you "it was my car's window."

But it's equally common for nouns to act as adjectives for another noun, as in "Hey, look, I found a piece of glass!  I think it came from a *car window*."